# How to use linked bag to remove duplicates from a 1-d array?

Tags: java

My assignment is to convert 2d to 1d array in the linked bag class. Then remove the duplicates in the linked bag.I 
  am stuck on how to remove the duplicates.

```
 enter code here
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class LinkedBag<T> implements PrimaryDataStructureBagInterface<T> {

private Node firstNode;
private int numberOfEntries;

public LinkedBag() {
    firstNode = null;
    numberOfEntries = 0;
}

@Override
public boolean removeAllOccurrences(T[][] entries) {
    // convert 2d into 1d array
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(int i =0; i< entries.length; i++) {
        for(int j =0; j< entries[i].length; j++){
            list.add((Character) entries[i][j]);
```

Comment: Please put the expected inputs and outputs of this program at text here, not as a link.

Comment: @NomadMaker there isn't an expected input and the output was sent to me as a pdf, I am not sure how to convert it to text